# Dynamic error message make it in if condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have playing with some API for my requirements. In response iam getting some dynamic error messages. I want to put the error message in if condition so inside the condition i can write some code based on my requirements.

This is the error message.

"errormessage"=>"Login session for token webapi2-26631123a246241356880 is expired or invalid."

This webapi2-26631123a246241356880 will generate dynamically.. I like to have if condition with this dynamic error message.

Comment: This is pretty basic; what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
h = {"errormessage"=>"Login session for token webapi2-26631123a246241356880 is expired or invalid."}
h["errormessage"].include? "webapi2-" #=> true
if h["errormessage"].include? "webapi2-" 
  #your code here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@webapi = Webapi.find(params[:token])
if coondition true
  #your logic here
 else
  flash[:alert] = "Login session for token " + @webapi.token + "is expired or invalid."
  render :template => 'path/to/template'
end
```